# Karma tests fail on DatePipe in PhantomJS but not Chrome

Tags: angular, testing, phantomjs, karma-jasmine

Running Karma tests on my angular app return passed tests when I use chrome. But when I use PhantomJS I get a slew of failures for the date pipe as such

```
Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '2017-01-03 14:09:46' for pipe 'DatePipe'
```

Why are my tests passing when I run the tests in Chrome, but failing when I run the tests in PhantomJS?

I had some tests failing because of a missing polyfill for phantomjs. Might this also be the case for the datepipe?

Comment: This error depends on regex match https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5.0.3/packages/common/src/pipes/date_pipe.ts#L14 . And it's unclear how it can be different in Chrome. It should be '2017-01-03T14:09:46' to pass.

Comment: Well not quite the answer I was hoping for but adding the T in all my datetime strings  solved the errors.

Comment: Yes, `T` is a known issue for date parsing.